# NavigationView menu item with heading issue

Tags: android, android-navigationview

Inside my NavigationView menu I have these items. There are some items with heading which is having some issues I think because when I used `android:checkableBehavior` it's not affected or doesn't show that it's selected or being highlighted. The items highlighted are only the nav1, nav2, nav3 items on the menu for the Drawer Layout. What I wanted to achieve is when the user clicks on the items with some headings on it like the nav4, or nav5 item It should get highlighted when selected.

```
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_1" android:icon="@drawable/ic_1"
            android:title="@string/nav1" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_2" android:icon="@drawable/ic_2"
            android:title="@string/nav2" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_3" android:icon="@drawable/ic_3"
            android:title="@string/nav3" />

        <item android:title="@string/heading1">
            <menu >
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_4" android:icon="@drawable/ic_4"
                    android:title="@string/nav4"/>
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_5" android:icon="@drawable/ic_5"
                    android:title="@string/nav5" />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
```

Comment: if i understand well nav4 and nav5 are not highlighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want nav4 and nav5 to get highlighted too change to this:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_1" android:icon="@drawable/ic_1"
        android:title="@string/nav1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_2" android:icon="@drawable/ic_2"
        android:title="@string/nav2" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_3" android:icon="@drawable/ic_3"
        android:title="@string/nav3" />

    <item android:title="@string/heading1">
        <menu >
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_4" android:icon="@drawable/ic_4"
                android:title="@string/nav4"/>
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_5" android:icon="@drawable/ic_5"
                android:title="@string/nav5" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
```